# value of state updated on second call

Tags: reactjs, setstate

The problem is that **toDay**  changes on second call

```
const handleToDay = day => {
    setToDay(day)  
  }
```

```
 <Select
  id="days"
  name="days"
  value={toDay}
  onChange={handleToDay}
  options={daysOption}
 />
```

Comment: Can you show how you're updating the state? It would be great if you could create a sandbox.

Comment: Make sure that you are not console.logging to see if its changing because it will be lagging by one update since state updates are async... to make sure that you are updating the value use a functions instead `setToDat(() => day);`

Comment: Please provide some more context. A little more code, where exactly you're seeing the value not update. A runnable example would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

the code that you are putting this in, is that in a lifecycle method like ComponentWillUpdate and / or useEffect Hook, because if not you would have to place it inside one so that the DOM knows when to render it. I hope it makes sense. I can provide links where you can learn about these lifecycle events used in class based components or useEffect which is used in functional components in React.

Comment: Great! Keep coding.